# Toggle div when second div is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show a hidden div when a second div is shown. The second div is a dropdown that changes class when someone clicks a menuitem. I first tried to show the hidden div on hover, but then it wont show going to the dropdown. I then tried to toogle it with click, but it goes out of sync when clicking around the menuitems. My question is if I can show the div related to the second divs changing class. or if i need to dig into the javascript that changes the second divs class and somehow add my first div there?

Script I tried:

```
$('document').ready(
    function() {
        $('a.megamenu_drop').mouseover(function(){
            $('#site-overlay').show();
        })
        .mouseout(function(){
            $('#site-overlay').hide();
        });
    });
```

Fiddle with the code:https://jsfiddle.net/Jerryskate/doxdmxmL/

As you can see, on hover the hidden div site-overlay is shown. I want to show this div when the dropdown is active instead.

Could this be a correct approach - My li element for the menu are getting a class of active and im trying to target that. This script works in console, but not live. I guess I cant load it at just pageload for it to work?

```
$('document').ready(
function() {
if($('li').hasClass('active')) {
 $("#site-overlay").addClass("active");
 }
 });
```

Comment: It's really hard to parse your question, and your code sample is enormous. Try breaking it up into smaller bits, and asking your question in a different way, for a better chance at someone being able to help. As it stands, I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be seeing in your fiddle nor what the desired behavior is.

Comment: Sorry for that. removed code and hopefully explained it better. @Palpatim

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:** I just now saw your fiddle example. I have done a little modification in CSS.

```
.megamenu > li .megamenu_drop{
    padding-top: 21px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("a.megamenu_drop,.dropdown_fullwidth").hover(
            function () {
                $("#site-overlay").show();
            },
            function () {
                $("#site-overlay").hide();
            }

        );
```

Check out here https://jsfiddle.net/YameenYasin/doxdmxmL/13/
and let me know if this is what you want.

Since you are opening thedropdown on click, so a better approach would be to show the site-overlay only when the dropdown is active.

```
$(".dropdown_fullwidth").hover(
                function () {
                    $("#site-overlay").show();
                },
                function () {
                    $("#site-overlay").hide();
                }

            );
```

Comment: Hmm. The fiddle example you show didnt work? I want the div site-overlay to show when the dropdown is active, it ses an overlay sothe menu shows better. The fiddle is a little missguiden, since the real menu have a toggle function. you click it, the dropdown goes from display none to block. when this happens i want the overlay div to show aswell. @Yameen

Comment: Oh I am sorry. You mean you want to have a grey background when you have menu active ?

Comment: yeah basically. I want to show the site-overlay div, which is a black transparent background.

Comment: Check the fiddle and let me know if this was helpful :)

Comment: Well thats kinda what i want, and thats where i was at :D. The problem is that you hover the button and the overlay show, great, but then you go down to the megamenu, and then the overlay is gone. So for this i have set the megamenu to show on click only. the menus script sets the dropdown to display when you click it, and i wanted to show the overlay depending on the dropdowns class for it to work as excpected. you can see the menu live here: shop.xeptor.se.

Comment: I cant show the div on the click on the button either, cause it would work for the first button. you click it, the overlay shows. Most people would them click on next menuitem without closing the first one, and on that click it would then hide the overlay, which is wrong then. So it has to be in relation to when the dropdown is shown.

Comment: I have modified the code and I have tested the above code on your site and it works fine. Copy the jquery and paste it into console and test it.

Comment: Yeah just tried it. It still isnt the wanted behavior. It does show when hover the dropdown, but it should be shown on the click, or it will ook buggy and confusing. Thats why i wanted to see if its was javascript way to toggle the div related to the changes in class of the dropdown. :)